# How to determine this Mobius transformation to these regions?

Tags: complex-analysis

the transformation of the form $f(z)= \displaystyle\frac{az+b}{ac+d}$ the maps $D(i,1)$ to $ L =[ z \in \mathbb{C}: \pi/4 < arg(z) < 5\pi/4]$ such that $f(4i) = -4$ and $f(2i) = 0$.

What i tried to do was to form a linear system involving the two conditions noticing that $-d/c \in D(i,1)$ since a cirle is transformed in a line.

But doing this i get to nowhere since i need one more equation to find all the coeficients.

Any help or a hint of another method to do this?

Comment: I'm guessing this is for a course called "Complex ***Analysis***", right? But to get to the point: a "less analytic way" than WHAT?

Comment: less algebric way i mean

Comment: less algebraic than WHAT? Do you have some method you were thinking of using that we can try to do better than? Because right now if I type out a whole solution, you might say, "Oh, no, that's the algebraic one I was thinking of." I'd rather see YOU do the work of clarifying the question than see ME waste my time.

Comment: @JohnHughes sorry for the bad description of my question. i made a edit on the post, could u please say something about my try?